# accumulation points of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Find all of the accumulation points of the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, where 
$x_n\in\mathbb{R}^2$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is defined by

$x_n:= (1+(-1)^n,2^n+(-2)^n)$

Solution:

$\{x_n\}$ can be split into 2 sub sequences, corresponding to when $n$ is odd or even:

$x_{2k} := (1 + 1, 2^{2k} + 2^{2k}) = (2, 2^{2k+1})$

$x_{2k+1} = (1 - 1, 2^{2k+1} - 2^{2k+1}) = (0, 0)$

as $\{x_{2k+1}\}$ is a sequence of points with values $(0,0)$, it follows that it will have one accumulation point at $(0, 0)$.

as the second component of $\{x_{2k}\}$ goes to infinity as $n \rightarrow \infty$, it follows that it will not have any accumulation points.

Therefore, this sequence has one accumulation point at $(0, 0)$.

is this reasoning sufficient?

Comment: What does it mean to say that a sequence is “a sequence of points with values $(0,0)$”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I think it is another way of saying "$x_{2k + 1}$ is identically $(0,0)$"

Comment: yes, I mean if you wrote it out it would be (0,0), (0,0), (0,0) ... (0,0). So $x_{2k+1} = (0, 0)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: It is not sufficient. You are assuming the following: if a sequence is split into two subsequences, then the union of the accumulation points of the two subsequences is equal to the accumulation points of the original sequence. But you haven't proved that this is true.

Answer (score 1):

For your sequence, the only accumulation point is $(0,0)$.  For the definition requires that every nbhd of an accumulation point $x$ contain infinitely many points of the sequence.